# Nested arrays don't behave the same

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm creating a nested array to store some letters in two different ways. The first way is this:

```
Array.new(rows, Array.new(columns){ O })
```

The second way is this:

```
Array.new(rows) do
  Array.new(columns) { O }
end
```

They look exactly the same:

```
[["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
 ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
 ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
 ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
 ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
 ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]]
```

When I want to replace a position with another letter and do:

```
array[1][3] = R
```

with the array generated in the first way, the whole first column will be turned into `R`. With the second way, only the position `[1][3]` will be replaced to contain `R`.

I'm wondering what the difference is between both ways of doing this.

Comment: Note that although the first block is important, the second (inner) block is redundant – you can just write `Array.new(columns, 0)`.

Comment: @Stefan wouldn't that create the same object for all positions? So if i change one of the 0, wouldn't that change all of them? As technically from what I understood it is the -same- object

Comment: @Stefan is correct.  The difference in the case of the innermost nested array is that you are *replacing* the object (an integer literal) with a different object (a string literal or a different integer). Literals are not reused in ruby, which is why we have symbols (kind of like forcing reuse of identical symbols).  It would be the same as, for example, using your first snippet but instead of doing `a[1][3] = R`, you do `a[1] = [0, 0, 0, R, 0]`

Comment: @nullwriter you can't change `0` to something else, it's immutable. A block is only needed for mutable objects, like an array, a hash or a string.

Comment: @Xavier _"Literals are not reused in ruby"_ – that depends. The literals `0`, `1.5`, `true`, `nil` or `:foo` return the same object every time, whereas `[]`, `{}`, `/foo/` or `1..2` create new objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first example: `Array.new(rows, Array.new(columns){ O })`, the second argument specifies the default value for the array *as an object reference*.  In other words, in the first example you are specifying that the same exact object be used for each row,  whereas in the second, block version, that expression is evaluated separately for each row, giving you unique objects that can be changed independently.

See here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new-label-Common+gotchas

Taken from the above link:

> When sending the second parameter, the same object will be used as the
>   value for all the array elements:
>
> ```
> a = Array.new(2, Hash.new)
> # => [{}, {}]
>
> a[0]['cat'] = 'feline'
> a # => [{"cat"=>"feline"}, {"cat"=>"feline"}]
>
> a[1]['cat'] = 'Felix'
> a # => [{"cat"=>"Felix"}, {"cat"=>"Felix"}]
> ```
>
> Since all the Array elements store the same hash, changes to one of
>   them will affect them all.
>
> If multiple copies are what you want, you should use the block version
>   which uses the result of that block each time an element of the array
>   needs to be initialized:
>
> ```
> a = Array.new(2) { Hash.new }
> a[0]['cat'] = 'feline'
> a # => [{"cat"=>"feline"}, {}]
> ```

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks. Just started with ruby! (Gotcha!)

Comment: "[T]he second argument [**does not**] specif[y] the default value for the array as an object reference." It specifies **the value** for the array.

Comment: That's true, however I was just borrowing the terminology used in the ruby docs, which calls the second param `default`, as does the actual ruby source code.